# React Native (Expo) - Cannot read property 'getIosIdForVendorAsync' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm working on an Expo based React Native app and recently I've run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out. When I generate a build (I'm using eas build) everything goes smoothly, the app opens normally on Android simulators, but not on iOS.

My app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App name",
    "slug": "app-slug",
    "owner": "app owner",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#F15C17"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSFaceIDUsageDescription": "Permitir que $(PRODUCT_NAME) utilize o Face ID."
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "my.bundle"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#F15C17"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC",
        "android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"
      ],
      "package": "my.package"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "apiUrl": "api-url",
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "project-id"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-local-authentication",
        {
          "faceIDPermission": "Permitir que $(PRODUCT_NAME) utilize o Face ID."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

My eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.17.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

When I try to open the app on the iPhone simulator, I get the message "Cannot read property 'getIosIdForVendorAsync' of undefined".

I tried uninstalling the packages that require a build for the app to run on a simulator (previously Expo Go was enough), and even though the app runs with no problems on Expo Go, the  build version on the simulator just will not open, so maybe I messed something up in the build config but I'm really not sure.

Right now I can't think of a reason why this works on an Android emulator but not iOS, and since Expo takes care of the build process for both platforms (which as I said happens with no errors), I'm currently out of theories as to why this is happening.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76zYr.png)

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: What did it for me was updating the EAS CLI and changing the version in eas.json to ">= 5.8.0" and adding expo-application to the dependencies.